# Count distinct, exact string values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've seen many examples of questions on Stack Exchange and elsewhere around the web of people wanting to count distinct values in an Excel range using a formula. Newer versions of Excel have the [`DISTINCT` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/distinct-function-dax-HA102838209.aspx) but I'm not yet on Excel 2013.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel) shows an elegant formula:

```
SUM(1/COUNTIF(range, range))
```

As an array formula, this counts the distinct values but will use Excel's default case-insensitive comparison. All the other examples that I've found (mostly variants on `SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNTIF` expressions) are also case-insensitive. Is there a simple way to use `EXACT` or similar functionality within the `COUNTIF` and force a case-sensitive unique count?

Comment: simpliest way is to create UDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count distincts in **A1** thru **A100** that is case sensitive use the array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/IF($A$1:$A$100<>"", FREQUENCY(IF(EXACT($A$1:$A$100, TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$100)), MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$100), ROW($A$1:$A$100)), ""), MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$100), ROW($A$1:$A$100))), 0), 0))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I've been known for my formula wizardry but I do believe I need to be sending you my trophy.

Comment: @Bmo  Thanks!............the formula works, but it is so ugly I would use a **Collection-based** UDF