# Count unique values excel formula with Blanks

Tags: excel, count, sum, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to count unique values in excel by using a formula.  I have tried using the formula below but it returns a #DIV!/0 error because I have blanks in my range.  Is there anyway to count unique values in a range with blanks by using a formula? Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(Usage!J2:J6000,Usage!J2:J6000))
```

Comment: Im not sure about the unique values part, but to count around the blanks, you should use the formula: `=countif([range you need], "<>"&"")` this will count ever cell within the range that has some value in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count unique values in a column in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel)

Comment: If you use `SUMPRODUCT` in place of `SUM` the formula does not have to be entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have to compensate for blank cells, take the formula and adjust the numerator of your count unique to check for non-blanks then add a zero-length string to the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)'s criteria argument.

`=SUMPRODUCT((Usage!J2:J6000<>"")/COUNTIF(Usage!J2:J6000,Usage!J2:J6000&""))`

Checking for non-blank cells in the numerator means that any blank cell will return a zero. Any fraction with a zero in its numerator will be zero no matter what the denominator is. The empty string appended to the criteria portion of the COUNTIF is sufficient to avoid #DIV/0! errors.

More information at [Count Unique with SUMPRODUCT() Breakdown](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `if` function to verify blank cells.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214244

```
if not blank cells:
 sum
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.