# Count the number of unique text cells in two columns in Excel-Calc

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

Given the following file:

> Column A---- Column D
>
> alfa         ----  (blank)
>
> beta         ----  beta
>
> (blank)      ----  gamma
>
> (blank)      ----  (blank)
>
> omega  ----  omega

I want to count the number of unique text cells in the two columns, therefore 4:

```
alfa, beta, gamma, omega
```

At the moment I roughly solved by this formula:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A6)+COUNTA(D2:D6)-SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6=D2:D6)*(LEN(A2:A6)>0))
```

Is there any simpler and more elegant way to do the same thing?

Comment: Your sample references columns A and D, but your formula A and B.

Comment: I guess it also depends on whether you want a generic solution which will work for any number of columns, not just two.

Comment: @XORLX It is sufficient for just two columns.

Comment: If the data set were large it might be worthwhile to connect Base or Access to the spreadsheet and use an SQL query.  For a smaller dataset maybe check out [this older StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel) for some ideas.