# Excel Array formulas details and guidance needed (INDEX,MATCH and SUM/COUNTIF)

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

So I'm having difficulties understanding fully how arrays works and when they are used by excel and specifically what happens in the background.

1. From reading the past few hours I understand that one of the reasons my Index Match doesn't work without array is simply because its a multicriteria Match that I use as below:

   ```
   {=INDEX(D30:E36,MATCH(F33&G33,B30:B36&C30:C36),2)}
   ```

   From what I understand the reason is that Match returns a {x,y} result which classifies it as an array formula. But considering the point is to get a row number, if the row I'm looking for is 5 then Match will return a {5,5} for row number for Index. And then Index interprets this as just 5? or what exactly happens in the background here?
2. Then I found an article which showed how to circumvent the array formula and not need ctrl+shift+enter as shown below. How does the below change things and what happens in the background?

   ```
   =INDEX(D30:E36,MATCH(F33&G33,INDEX(B30:B36&C30:C36)),2)
   ```
3. The below is a an array SUM/COUNTIF formula which counts unique cells only which does not work without array brackets. Why is that and how does it work? It involves maths so I'm not sure.

   ```
   {=SUM(1/(COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5)))}
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: *From what I understand the reason is that Match returns a {x,y} result which classifies it as an array formula.* In this case, it doesn't. It will return a single result. Your `MATCH` is searching for the *single* value of `F33&G33`, which is not an *array*, but rather the *concatenation* of two values. E.g. if `F33` and `G33` are `2` and `5`, then `F33&G33` is `25`, but `F33:G33` is `{2,5}` (which is an array).

Comment: Re: question 3 - it's not quite the same but see my answer here and some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel/18588144#18588144

Comment: For general info on array formulas see here - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx

Comment: F9 higlighted parts of the formulas to see the array objects they create, that helps to understand waht is happening behind the scenes