# How to connect the code in excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel-formula, countif

Can anybody help me, I'm trying to find out the age band of listed codes, using the VBA `CountIfs` function with the data shown below? .

**Age band of the codes:**

[image: Age band of the codes]

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: I'll show you how to do this quickly (the easy way, without VBA) but I need to know, what happens if the value is `5`?  **Should it be counted a `0 to 5` or `5 to 10`, or *both***?  If you require an answer with VBA, it's important that you show the code you've tried so far.  (See "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]" and also [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(See below to download sample file.)</sup>

You could do it easier without VBA like this:

[image: screenshot example]

### The formula in `E4` is:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$15,"="&$D4,$B$1:$B$15,">=" &E$2,$B$1:$B$15,"<="&E$3)
```

...but if you *need* to do this in VBA for some reason, you can do basically the same thing with a few syntax changes:

This would give the same value as `E4`:

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A15"), Range("D4"), _
    Range("B1:B15"), ">=" & Range("E2"), Range("B1:B15"), "<=" & Range("E3"))
```

---

Or, instead of specifying the ranges directly in the formula (like if you were planning on looping through the cells or specifying individuals):

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lowerLimit As Range, upperLimit As Range, findName As Range
    Dim rangeNames As Range, rangeValues As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set lowerLimit = ws.Range("E2") 'or specify actual values instead of "Range"'s
    Set upperLimit = ws.Range("E3")
    Set findName = ws.Range("D4")
    Set rangeNames = ws.Range("A1:A15")
    Set rangeValues = ws.Range("B1:B15")
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rangeNames, findName, rangeValues, _
        ">=" & lowerLimit, rangeValues, "<=" & upperLimit)
End Sub
```

---

## Download Sample File:

- You *can* view sample file used above on [JumpShare here](http://jmp.sh/KUMKaYV), but `COUNTIFS` and VBA is not supported in the online viewer.
- The Jumpshare page also has a download link, or [direct link here](https://storage.jumpshare.com/dl/dWIIQW68ArubfzlBMybl5Z9QqM-Y-bA510tJslmIBbVIeyCYq4mLadTX_wdjQsozKz5CftbsKuZk2J6ZyMoHWA?s=7973783efa82beac9728704c89d88fe9ca5c3dc0&dl=1).  Note that the file contains VBA so you may get an "unknown code" (etc) warning.

---

## More Information:

- Office.com : **[COUNTIFS Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**
- Excejet : **[Excel COUNTIFS Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function)**
- MSDN : **[WorksheetFunction.CountIfs Method (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countifs-method-excel)**
- Stack Overflow : **[Count unique values in a column in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588144/8112776)**