# Excel Formula - Return unique count of range based on multiple criteria from different tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**I have three tables:** Parties, Document Detail and Document. *(Note, they are not table formatted, so all references are based on cell and sheet location, not table aliases)*

I want to return a unique count of the parties in each Document using an Excel Formula. My problem is, I would usually use a `=COUNTIFS()` formula for this, which would be something like the following, which I would put in `B2` of Sheet 3 (Document table):

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!A2)
```

But this will only return the count of one criteria at a time, not a count checking for all values of the parties table per document. I understand it should be able to be done with an array formula, but I can't figure it out. Bonus points if someone can figure out how to do it with a non-array formula!

---

**Sheet1 - Parties Table**

```
       A       
1|Parties          |
 +-----------------+
2|Education Officer|
3|Elder            |
4|Family Support   |
5|Interpreter      |
```

**Sheet2 - Document Detail Table**

```
       A            B
1 |Doc ID |  Party          |
  +-------+-----------------+
2 |FID0001|Education Officer|
3 |FID0001|Elder            |
4 |FID0001|Education Officer|
5 |FID0001|                 |
6 |FID0001|                 |
7 |FID0002|Elder            |
8 |FID0002|Interpreter      |
9 |FID0002|Family Support   |
10|FID0002|                 |
```

**Sheet3 - *(Desired Result)* - Document Table**

```
    A        B
1|Doc ID |Party Count|
 +-------+-----------+
2|FID0001|  2        |
3|FID0002|  3        |
```

---

**TL:DR**

What combination of Excel formulas can I use to return the number of unique parties referenced in each document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588144/445425) by [Barry Houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini) and expanded to include the DocID criteria

Put a helper column on `Sheet2`, lets say in colum `C`

```
=IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B:$B,$A:$A,$A:$A),0)
```

and copy down for all data rows

Then, in `Sheet3` Party Count Formula is

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet2!$A:$A,$A:$A)
```

---

The non-Implicit Intersection versions

Sheet2 cell C1

```
=IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$A:$A,$A1),0)
```

Sheet3 cell B2

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet2!$A:$A,$A2)
```

Comment: That's great, it does what I need thank you! In the first part of the formula is there any reason `($A:$A=$A:$A)` isn't just "1"?

Comment: That is using "Implicit Intersection" [See here](http://www.excelcodex.com/2012/05/excel-intersection-101-implicit-intersection/).  You _can_ use `$A:$A=$A1` etc if you want

Comment: I don't think I was clear which formula I was talking about, apologies. `=IFERROR(($A:$A=$A:$A)/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B:$B,$A:$A,$A:$A),0)` In this formula, the first comparison `($A:$A=$A:$A)` will always evaluate to 1 or `TRUE`. From my understanding of implicit intersections, this formula would be evaluating per row `A1=A1` or `A2=A2` etc. which will also always evaluate to 1 or `TRUE`. So is there any reason the formula should not be simplified to `=IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B:$B,$A:$A,$A:$A),0)`? Also thank you for the resource, it was very helpful :)

Comment: @girlvsdata sorry, I was too focused on the Implicit Intersection. You are right, it can be `=IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B:$B,$A:$A,$A:$A),0)`  I'll update